# ag-grid ampersand not showing correctly in table

Tags: ag-grid, ampersand

when using `&amp;` characters which css correctly converts to `&`, in ag-grid, it is not showing correctly.
does any one has a hint how to use this correctly?

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/D5ftAOYxFtUiaeIt

Comment: just use `&`. it works: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/n3HhiLEkumoTA78z

Answer (score 0):

i got the data from the database.
so the cell renderer solved my issue.

```
this.defaultColDef = {
  cellRenderer: function(params) {
    return params.value ? params.value : '';
  }
};
```

and only thing that remains unresolved is when filtering, it shows html code instead of just &.
[image: filtering]

solved:

```
defaultColDef: {
  filter: true,
  sortable: true,
  resizable: true,
  filterParams: {
    cellRenderer: function (params) {
      return params.value ? params.value : '';
    }
  },
  cellRenderer: function (params) {
    return params.value ? params.value : '';
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, your source data should not be HTML escaped. Just make your source data use `&` instead of `&amp;`, as the comment already says.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in you case a **valueGetter** would have been more appropriate since you are only manipulating the text of your cell and not the formatting:

```
valueGetter: function (params) {
  return params.value ? params.value : '';
}
```